# apacheで503エラー画面に遷移させる際、ユーザーエージェントがIPhoneである場合は別のHTMLに遷移させたい

Tags: iphone, apache

apacheのhttpd.confで503エラー画面に遷移させる際、ユーザーエージェントがIPhoneである場合はIPhoneError.htmlに遷移させたいです。
また、現在は下記の記述で、全てのアクセスをerror.htmlに飛ばしています↓

```html
＜httpd.conf＞
ErrorDocument 503 /error.html
```

記述方法の分かる方がいましたら、ご教授をお願いします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

以下が参考になるでしょうか。(httpd.confではありませんが)
あらかじめPC/スマートデバイス用に振り分けておくのが一番楽な方法ではありますが。

[PC版とスマートフォン版サイトを自動振り分けする方法](http://allabout.co.jp/gm/gc/386483/3/)